# Mobx @inject @observer order

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have a fetch in my `componentDidMount` that does not refresh the `appState` data when I do `@observer @inject('appState')` but it would consistently work when I have `@inject('appState') @observer` .

At the same time, I'm getting a warning in the console that my order is wrong.

`Mobx observer: You are trying to use 'observer' on a component that already has 'inject'. Please apply 'observer' before applying 'inject'`

Which is the correct order and why?

Comment: `@inject('appState') @observer` is the correct order. I also think it works without `@observer`, i.e. just `@inject('appState')`.

Comment: @Tholle `@inject('appState') @observer` is what is working for me. Apparently the warning message is wrong. Without `@observer` is not working =)

Comment: @Tholle after I replaced all the orders, the warning message disappeared. It looks like it was some kind of typo in Mobx and they had the warning message incorrectly flipped. =)

Comment: Ah, you're right. I always do `@inject(...) @observer`, but I must've misunderstood [**this blog post**](https://twitter.com/mweststrate/status/872550577993068544), since I thought just `@inject` worked as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorators are sugar for function calls, `so @a @b class C` is a similar to `a(b(class C))`, in other words, the inner most (or right most) is the first applied decorator. So applying `observer` before applying `inject` means: `inject("stores")(observer(Component))`, in other words, the order that works for you is the order that is intended: `@inject('appState') @oberver Component`